# Have I any opportunity to attach decode json struct to http.Request variable in go lang

Tags: json, go

I have a situation some methods use one link to request *http.Request. In it body it contains json. And I need to get different data from that json. But I don't want to decode json every time in every method again and again. Can I decode once and attach the link of struct or json (in string) to request. I try to find the solution but I didn't found anything. I know that I can create my own functional for this, but I think that such packages like "*http.Request" or "github.com/gorilla/mux" should have such functionality from the box. Anyone known?

Comment: Do you want to pass data between different handlers during the same request?

Comment: @JimB, yes I want it)

Comment: The most commonly used context package is https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/context. You need to change the signature of your handlers and pass that context value through, or you could use a global context handler like http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/context